# Python dictionary not filling properly in for loop

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am currently making some test data for my browser-based javascript database. I scraped some data off of a web-site and filled a python list with it. Now i am trying to populate a dictionary, add some other random data and make a json file. My variables:

- cpartyList: a list of tuples. Every tuple consist of 4 strings: Number1(unique), Number2, fullname, address;
- cpartyDict: a python dictionary for later serialization to json file;

cpartyList consists of 40 tuples. Now, populating my dictionary with data:

```
for org in cpartyList:
    #just to make shure that a tuple is 4 units and Number1 is unique
    if len(org) == 4 and org[0] not in cpartyDict.keys():
        cpartyDict[org[0]] = {
            "Number1": org[0],
            "Number2": org[1],
            "shortname": "",
            "fullname": org[2],
            "contacts": {
                "adressOfficial": org[3],
                "adressPostal": org[3],
                "phone": ''.join([str(random.randint(0,9)) for i in range(11)])
            }
        }

print(cpartyDict,keys())
```

But in return i only get 2 last tuples in my dictionary (cpartyDict.keys() has two keys in it). What is wrong?

Comment: can you show the list?? and did you initialised a blank dictionary before the for loop

Comment: "Is your computer plugged in in an outlet?" ha ha . Yes, i did initialize a blank dict and a list. Showing the list will take some time as i managed to overwrite my programm, erasing data. Damn it. Thankfully, it a small script.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `else` with some debugging output to your (seemingly unneccessary) `if`? The way your code is now, you never know why something went wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you provide an example of your data such that others can reproduce your output, you are more likely to find someone willing to help.

Comment: Add cpartyList contents.

Comment: Your code works when I initialize `cpartyDict` as an empty dict and `cpartyList` as you described. No one can help you without giving us the contents of theses variables.

Comment: Wow! I am new to stackoverflow, and what a flow of responses. As i mentioned earlier, i have accidentally deleted script, and will provide more info later (its a short script), please, please stand by. I wanted to include cpartyList initially, but did not find how to hide large chunks of text, and decided not to).

Comment: tobias_k i added else statement, and found out almost all my Number 1(org[0]) are identicall. Thanks, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**YOUR CODE IS WORKING..**

```
import random
import pprint

cpartyList= [

  (1,'c1','c2','c3'),
  (2,'c1','c2','c3','c4'),
  (3,'c1','c2','c3'),
  (4,'c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'),
  (5,'c1','c2','c3'),
  (6,'c1','c2','c3')
  ]
cpartyDict = {}


for org in cpartyList:
    #just to make shure that a tuple is 4 units and Number1 is unique
    if len(org) == 4 and org[0] not in cpartyDict.keys():
        cpartyDict[org[0]] = {
            "Number1": org[0],
            "Number2": org[1],
            "shortname": "",
            "fullname": org[2],
            "contacts": {
                "adressOfficial": org[3],
                "adressPostal": org[3],
                "phone": ''.join([str(random.randint(0,9)) for i in range(11)])
            }
        }

pprint.pprint(cpartyDict)
```

**RESULT**

```
{1: {'Number1': 1,
     'Number2': 'c1',
     'contacts': {'adressOfficial': 'c3',
                  'adressPostal': 'c3',
                  'phone': '78858320412'},
     'fullname': 'c2',
     'shortname': ''},
 3: {'Number1': 3,
     'Number2': 'c1',
     'contacts': {'adressOfficial': 'c3',
                  'adressPostal': 'c3',
                  'phone': '40650498587'},
     'fullname': 'c2',
     'shortname': ''},
 5: {'Number1': 5,
     'Number2': 'c1',
     'contacts': {'adressOfficial': 'c3',
                  'adressPostal': 'c3',
                  'phone': '17115487396'},
     'fullname': 'c2',
     'shortname': ''},
 6: {'Number1': 6,
     'Number2': 'c1',
     'contacts': {'adressOfficial': 'c3',
                  'adressPostal': 'c3',
                  'phone': '54560186092'},
     'fullname': 'c2',
     'shortname': ''}}
```

Comment: I followed tobias_k advise to add an else statement, and it turned out that i have filled cpartyList with identicall Number1 somehow, so the for loop always overwrites this one key, and in the end i get only 2 entries in my dict. Thanks to everybody, sorry for wasting your time on this super shitty question!